# Mistake in B. Jacobs book Categorical Logic and Type Theory?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory, categorical-logic

Lemma 1.8.9 in B. Jacobs book *Categorical Logic and Type Theory* describes how a collection of fibre-wise adjoints of a morphism of fibrations can be promoted to a global adjoint.

> Let $p: \mathbb E \to \mathbb B$ and $q: \mathbb D \to \mathbb B$ be Grothendieck fibrations. Assume $H: \mathbb E \to \mathbb D$ is a  functor such that $qH = p$ and $H$ preserves cartesian morphisms. Then $H$ has a fibred left (respectively right) adjoint $K$ if and only if the following two conditions hold.

> (a) Each induced $H_I: \mathbb E_I \to \mathbb D_I$ has a left (respectively right) adjoint $K_J$.

> (b) The $K_J$ satisfy a Beck-Chevalley condition. For each morphism $u: I\to J$ in the base $\mathbb B$ the canonical natural transformation  $K_Iu^*\Rightarrow u^* K_J$ (respectively $u^*K_J \Rightarrow K_Iu^*$) is an isomorphism.

That $K$ is fibred just means that $pK = q$ and that $K$ preserves cartesian morphism. Jacobs uses the word *fibred* instead of the more  standard term *cartesian functor*.

In the proof Jacobs shows how to produce a left adjoint $K$ from the $K_J$ and states that the result for right adjoints (in brackets) can be proven in a similar way.

I am not sure that this is true. I believe that the correct dual result for right adjoints should involve cofibrations and cofibred functors instead of fibrations. At least that is the point where I get stuck when I try to dualize Jacobs proof. So my question is: Is Jacobs lemma 1.8.9 correct? Does it work out for both left and right adjoints?

**The rest of the question are just context, references and more details!**

Let me start by repeating Jacobs proof, so that I can point you to the exact place where I get stuck when I try to dualize it. So assume we are given fibre-wise left adjoints $K: \mathbb D_I \to \mathbb E_I$ of $H: \mathbb E_I \to \mathbb D_I$ for each object $I$ in the base category. I will denote all of them by the same letter $K$ to make the proof more readable. Consequently I will also denote all counits and units by the same letter $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$ respectively. Assume we have chosen a cleveage for both $p$ and $q$. We will show that $H$ has a total left adjoint $K: \mathbb D \to \mathbb E$ by showing that $(KX, \eta X: X \to HKX)$ is initial in $X \downarrow H$ and not just in the fibre $X \downarrow H_{qX}$. So take some $(Y,f: X \to HY)$. We need to show that there is $g: KX \to Y$ such that $f = Hg\circ \eta X$, and we need to show that there is only one such $g$. Let $u: I\to J$ be the image of $f$ in the base $\mathbb B$.

To see that there is some $g$, consider the cartesian lift $\overline uY: u^*Y \to Y$ of $u$ in $\mathbb E$ and apply $H$ to it. The resulting map $H(\overline uY)$ is cartesian in $\mathbb D$ because $H$ is fibred by assumption. We need a picture.

[image]

Because $H(\overline u Y)$ is cartesian, we get the map $X \to Hu^*Y$ which is already drawn in the picture. Now we can use the fact that $\eta X$ is initial in the fibre $\mathbb E_I$ to obtain a $k: KX \to u^*Y$ such as in the diagram. We can now set $g = \overline uY \circ k$.

I will skip over the rest of proof, because the relevant part is already there. Jacobs proceeds by showing that $g$ is unique. This yields $K$, and one doesn't need the Beck-Chevalley condition at all to produce $K$. The Beck-Chevalley condition is finally used to show that the functor $K$ is fibred (that is preserves cartesian morphisms).

Next let me show you where I get stuck when I try to perform the coproof. As before, assume that we are given fibre-wise right adjoints $K: \mathbb D_I \to \mathbb E_I$. We like to show that $H$ has a total right adjoint $K$ by showing that each $(X, \varepsilon X: HKX \to X)$ is terminal in all of $H\downarrow X$ and not just in its fibre. So take some $f: HY \to X$. Write $u: I\to J$ for the image of $f$ in the base category $\mathbb B$. We are in the following situation.

[image]

Now what? In the case of a left adjoint $K$ we proceeded by taking the pullback $u^*Y \to Y$ of $Y$, but we can't do this now. It seems like we need a cocartsian lift $\underline uY : Y \to u_*Y$. I am stuck. Am I missing something?

Relevant references: I checked out most of the references which are mentioned in chapter I of Jacobs book. I couldn't find the result anywhere else, except in B. Jacobs PhD thesis where they state it without a proof. The version of the lemma where $K$ is left adjoint appears as proposition 8.4.1. in Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra 2*, but they only state the result for left adjoints!

Comment: There is an H missing in the first picture. It should of course be $Hu^*Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Beck-Chevalley condition implies $H$ is a total right adjoint as follows.

Given a cartesian lift $u^*X\to X$, we have that $HY\to X$ factors as $HY\to HKu^*X\to u^*X\to X$ for a unique morphism $Y\to Ku^*X$. The Beck-Chevalley condition is that the unique vertical morphism $u^*KX\to Ku^*X$ for which $Hu^*KX\to HKX\to X$ factors as $Hu^*KX\to HKu^*X\to u^*X\to X$ is an isomorphism.

Its inverse is then an isomorphism $Ku^*X\to u^*KX$ such that $HKu^*X\to u^*X\to X$ is the same as $HKu^*X\to Hu^*KX\to HKX\to X$. It follows that $Y\to Ku^*X\to u^*KX\to KX$ is the unique morphism for which $HY\to X$ factors as $HY\to HKX\to X$.

Comment: I finally had time to work it out. Thank you!